# Do most men even sing that low (A3)?

Tags: voice

I just played a tune with the range of A3-D5 (I think that's the correct English terminology). When I started singing I had a problem with the A3.  The last melodic lines is A3-C#4-D4. 
This seem lika a popular key (Dm) for this song even though A3 seem low for some men. 
I feel a bit embarrased how I can find this difficult.
Do most men even sing this low?  And is this A3 note easy since it is a part of that melosic line?

Comment: A3 is not particularly low at all for a male voice. Are you sure you don't mean A2-D4? (Note that male voices are often written in treble-8vb clef, i.e. the notes are an octave lower than it looks. This _should_ be indicated by a small _8_ below the clef, but that is frequently omitted.)

Comment: A3 is well within the range of pretty much all male and female singers. It is the A right below middle C. I'm wondering if perhaps you were singing an octave lower than what was written?

Comment: I can hit C1 [*just*, only just] & when I was in my 20s could get to G4, though now it's more like C4 :( That was considered to be a better-than-normal range. I think one of us has to be out by an octave in our pitch recognition.

Comment: If not able to provide the score as graphic, then positioning in a note system with clef would help.

Comment: @Tetsujin — perhaps you're both mistaking the octave? C1 is really really really low (in the bass clef, it's under the 5th line below the staff). (I'm not saying you can't be able to hit it, but it is very rare, I would say.) This picture from Wiki could help sorting any mistakes out: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Scientific_pitch_notation_octaves_of_C.png

Comment: @Ramillies .. Ah, OK - I'm in MIDI. Middle C as C3, note 60, not classical C4. (That's what 10 years of working for Yamaha does to you ;) If we're going by the keyhole in the piano being C4, then I can reach C2 to C5 or so.

Comment: @Tetsujin: That's interesting, I didn't know before that MIDI was adding to the confusion in this way :—).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A3-D5 is a range accessible to contralto (low female voice) so I'll assume you are talking about A2-D4 instead.  The lowest regular note for baritone (or choir "bass") tends to be about E2.  The lowest regular note for a choir(?) tenor tends to be B2.  Being a "lead quart" below the tonic, touching that note tends to be easier than more extended or elaborate uses of it since it's without accent and the following line and overall harmonic frame is idiomatic enough that not getting the pitch impeccably is less noticeable than with other uses.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the range what you're on about- (A3 to D5), would probably be pretty comfortable for most well-trained Tenors, and also, for some exceptionally high Baritones. I'm a higher-end Bari and the range what you're on about's well within my comfortable range- (I wouldn't have much problem with that range at all!) A3's normally about the lowest that I'd be willing to sing- (although, for the record, I can sing all the way down to about E2 on a bloody good day.